# Update DataGridView data in Access Table

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a DataGridView linked to a database from Microsoft Access.
   In design view, I place the datagridview and in the properties pane, i setup the DataSource to the BindingSource created.

Once compiled, data can be watched in the grid, so all is alright by now.

The question is when I try to update data in the grid or insert a new row in the grid. The data is not updated or added to the Microsoft Access Table.

I created a button "Save & exit" which code is:

```
try
{
   this.plataformasBindingSource.EndEdit();
this.plataformasTableAdapter.Update(this.myDataSet.plataformas);
this.myDataSet.AcceptChanges();

} catch(System.Exception ex)
{
MessageBox.Show("Error");
}
```

At the beginning seems that all work, but when I open Micosoft Access and see the table, no data's been updated.

What's missing in my code?

Comment: Are you sure that you open the same database used by the application? What is your connectionstring?

Comment: Yes, there's no other one.

Comment: just try removing this.myDataSet.AcceptChanges(); line and see if it works.

Comment: @HiteshMistry, the same. Nothing upated in db.

Comment: I dunno how did you do the binding but just take a look at this link: this might help you to investigate further.. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xzb1zw3x(v=vs.100).aspx

Also pls put your binding code here, so that will help us to find out the cause of the problem.

Comment: @HiteshMistry At least I could guess the issue. It was due to I copied the database to the project instead of just link to it.